# How can I by using python to put excel data in a SQL Microsoft server Database

Tags: python, sql-server, excel, database, pandas

I'm stuck here, I wonder how I can transfer excel files with data to my database through python? Appreciate answers.

My local host is called `DB_01<br>`

My database is called `dbo.test1`

My tables contain:

```
a - int
b - int
c - int
d - int
e - int
f - int
```

Would it be okay to use Panda's here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. It is hard to answer your question with such little information, but I suggest you to look at using the [dataframe to_sql method of pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). This also requires creating a connection to your database with sqlalchemy.

Something along the lines of:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname', echo=False)

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv")

df.to_sql('your_table_name', con=engine)
```

The above is just pseudocode. [Check out the documentation on setting up a sqlalchemy connection here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you wfbbrown :)

Will the code by the same if my files is xlsx(shift csv to xlsx)?

I hope this can explain more( I use SQL Microsoft server)

My database look like this: ID   Block   BlockSell   BlockBuy  RejectedBlock  Netimports

And I want have data under each elementes.

Comment: You want to use pandas.read_excel instead of read_csv. See here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_excel.html